# error C2663: overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

please help me for this errors

code:

```
u16 ip_defragment(){
    u16 result;
    fragip_set::iterator i;
    IP_FRAGMENTED new_defrag;
    IP* pcurpack = (IP*) malloc(cur.len);
    memcpy(pcurpack, cur.data, cur.len);
    new_defrag.saddr = cur.saddr;
    new_defrag.daddr = cur.daddr;
    new_defrag.protocol = cur.ip.ppack->protocol;
    new_defrag.id = i2i(cur.ip.ppack->id);

    i = ip_frags.find(new_defrag);

    if(i != ip_frags.end()){
            i->packets.insert(pcurpack);
            const_cast<u16&>(i->cur_len) += cur.ip.len - cur.ip.hlen; 
            const_cast<u32&>(i->last_time) = time();
            if(!(cur.ip.bmore_fr) && (i->tot_len == 0)){
            const_cast<u16&>(i->tot_len) = cur.ip.fr_offs + cur.ip.len;
            }
            if(i->cur_len == i->tot_len){
                for(set<IP*>::iterator k = i->packets.begin(); k != i->packets.end(); k++){
                    // must copy to another buffer
                    if(i2i((*k)->frag_off) & IP_OFFMASK){
                        memcpy(ip_defrag_buffer, *k, (*k)->ihl<<2);
                    } else {
                        memcpy(ip_defrag_buffer + (i2i((*k)->frag_off) & IP_OFFMASK) * 8, 
                            *k + ((*k)->ihl<<2), (i2i((*k)->tot_len))-((*k)->ihl<<2));
                    }
                }
                IP* defr_ip = (IP*) &ip_defrag_buffer;
                defr_ip->tot_len = i2i(i->tot_len);
                defr_ip->frag_off = 0;
                result = i->tot_len;
                ip_frags.erase(i);
                return result;
            }
            return 0;
    }


    if(!(cur.ip.bmore_fr)){
        new_defrag.tot_len = cur.ip.fr_offs + cur.len;
    } else {
        new_defrag.tot_len = 0;
    }
    new_defrag.cur_len = cur.ip.len; // with header size
    new_defrag.last_time = time();
    i = ip_frags.insert(new_defrag).first;
    if(i != ip_frags.end())
        i->packets.insert(pcurpack);

    return 0;
}
```

compiled project and view only 2 errors similar

line 15 : `i->packets.insert(pcurpack);`

end line : `i->packets.insert(pcurpack);`

error with 2 lines : error C2663: 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::insert' : 4 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

```
IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::set<_Kty, _Pr, _Alloc>::insert [with _Kty=IP *, _Pr=std::less<IP *>, _Alloc=std::allocator<IP *>]" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match)
```

please help me?

Comment: Sounds like there is a problem with `i->packets`. Perhaps it is `const`?

Comment: Looks like `i` is an iterator pointing to a const object. So instead of trying to force things with `const_cast` everywhere, you should be asking yourself why this approach is wrong.

Comment: OK looking a little closer I think I can see what's wrong. `ip_frags` is of type `std::set`. The way sets work is once an item has been added to a set you cannot modify the item. That is what you are trying to do and the compiler is rightly preventing you. I suggest that you first remove the item from the set, make the changes you want to make to the item and then add it back to the set.

Answer (score 2):

I had exact same error with std::set, while passing it to a lambda expression:

```
C2663 'std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<_Kty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert': 5 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer
```

lambda expression prototype was:

```
[se1, ele1](auto val) {
    /* here I was editing se1 set, but above se1 is passed value type */
}
```

I have changed to:

```
[&se1, ele1](auto val) {
    /* now since se1 set is sent as reference type above, it is good to edit
       changes stays as I expect it to be
    */
}
```

Now compilation succeeds.

I used with count_if function, which calls the lamda expression for eac element, so the compiler knows that modifications should persist in set se1, which is perfectly logical.

If you desire to have the original set unchanged, then send a copy of it.